# Trying to install Windows XP, error shows up: CDBOOT: Cannot boot from CD - Code 4

Tags: windows-xp

So I made an executable to run a Windows XP IMA file, but it just keeps on showing this error:

```
CDBOOT: Cannot boot from CD - Code 4
```

I tried expanding the size of the CD image, but it just kept on failing. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please also include, what "tweaks" you already tried, in your question. Maybe someone might be able to help when more details are available.

Comment: I tried expanding the size of the CD image, but it just kept on failing.